# EXCEL: Why do I get #NAME? error on a function I've written?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have written this function in VBA EXCEL

```
    Public Function GIVENUM(InputRange As Range, numIndex As Integer) As Integer
    
    Dim RangeNonZeros As Integer
    RangeNonZeros = 0
    
    For Each Cell In InputRange
        If Not (Cell.Value = 0) Then
             RangeNonZeros = RangeNonZeros + 1
        End If
        Next Cell
    
    Dim RowNumbers(RangeNonZeros) As Integer
    RowNumbers(0) = 0
    
    Dim Index As Integer
    MinIndex = 0
    
    For Each Cell2 In InputRange
        If Not (Cell2.Value = 0) Then
            RowNumbers(MinIndex) = Cell2.Value
            MinIndex = MinIndex + 1
            End If
            Next Cell2
            
    GIVENUM = RowNumbers(numIndex)

    End Function
```

When I try type the funciton:
`=giveNum(U1:U9,R1)`

In a cell it shows #NAME? error in the cell.

Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure your VBA editor is tied to the current worksheet? As soon as I try using the function in Excel, the debugger throws up a compilation error and indicates that the `Dim RowNumbers(RangeNonZeros) As Integer` line is invalid because a constant expression is required as the array size, and you are trying to define the array dimensions using a variable.

Comment: Is your function in a regular code module?

Comment: You are getting that error because you do not have that code in a regular module as @TimWilliams mentioned. I have a strong feeling that you have the code in a sheet code module.

Answer (score 0):

From your code `Dim RowNumbers(RangeNonZeros) As Integer` is incorrect, RangeNonZeros needs to be constant expression. So try doing the following

```
Dim RowNumbers() As Integer
ReDim RowNumbers(RangeNonZeros)
```

You would have already seen the error if you had specified `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.
Also try declaring all variables you use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

as milo5m noted, using Option Explicit as the first line removes potential for many errors, always use it.

revised code that compiles and returns a value under testing. i have added further variable declareations, but Cell and Cell2 could be combined, using Redim Preserve

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GIVENUM(InputRange As Range, numIndex As Integer) As Integer
    
    Dim RangeNonZeros As Integer, cell As Range, cell2 As Range
    RangeNonZeros = 0
    
    For Each cell In InputRange
        If Not (cell.Value = 0) Then
             RangeNonZeros = RangeNonZeros + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ReDim RowNumbers(RangeNonZeros) As Integer
    RowNumbers(0) = 0
    
    Dim Index As Integer, MinIndex As Integer
    MinIndex = 0
    
    For Each cell2 In InputRange
        If Not (cell2.Value = 0) Then
            RowNumbers(MinIndex) = cell2.Value
            MinIndex = MinIndex + 1
        End If
    Next cell2
            
    GIVENUM = RowNumbers(numIndex)

End Function
```